# My acer is sick and it’s getting worse

Tags: maple

My acer branches are starting to die back and the leaves are falling off . It’s in a sheltered corner and it doesn’t get the full sun . I planted it in ericaceous soil and water it once a week but more if the soil dries out . It’s getting worse as the times goes on anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How long has your Acer been planted and is it in the ground or in a pot? Can you add a photo please?

Comment: We need more information (photo, age), but start watering much less. Watering when soil dry is valid just for pots and herbaceous plants (with shallow roots). For a tree: do few but more intense watering, so that water could go down, and root will follow.

Comment: My acer has been in the corner of the garden for 3 years and it is in the ground